# Python - Normalize data with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use Regex cleaning steps in Python to test to see if a pattern matches and if so, clean it to the specified carrier.

For instance, `if re.match("\bA\.?X\.?A\.?\b", Carrier): Carrier = CarrierMatch`

I've tried this by running a for loop on the number of raw carrier fields followed by another for loop on all of the match descriptions (just printing for now) and it takes FOREVER to run. Hoping someone out there has a better method.

Ideally I would like to see if it's possible to compile all match descriptions for Carrier I have in SQL (~2,000) and pull out the regex match pattern(s) to then use to append the carrier field.

For reference the SQL data fields are [raw_pattern], [Carrier]

```
import sys
import re 
import pyodbc
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
regexlist = list()
carrierlist = list()
rpt_id = 1234
#rpt_id = sys.argv[1]
plan_typs = list()

try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=xxxxxxxxx;'
                      'Database=xxxxxxxxx;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=xxxxx;')
except:
    print('Connection Failed')
    sys.exit()
 
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "delete from [dbo].[python_test1] where rpt_id = '""" + str(rpt_id) + """'"""
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "insert into [dbo].[python_test1](rpt_id, raw_carr_nm) select distinct rpt_id, raw_carr_nm from [dbo].[wrk_data] where rpt_id = '""" + str(rpt_id) + """'"""
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()

sql = "SELECT [raw_pattern], [Carrier] FROM [dbo].[ref_regex_t]"
regex1 = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

sql = "select * from [dbo].[python_test1] where rpt_id = '""" + str(rpt_id) + """'"""
carriers = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

for index, row in regex1.iterrows():
    regexlist.append(row['raw_pattern'])

for index, row in carriers.iterrows():
    carrierlist.append(row['Carrier'])

for i in carrierlist:
    print('"' + i + '"')
    for i in regexlist:
        print('"' + i + '"')
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `if re.search(r"\bA\.?X\.?A\b\.?", Carrier):`? Anyway, the pattern is not long and complex, the slowdown is not related to the regex pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes re.search :/ ....right it's not the pattern itself..... it's the fact that it would be running in a loop looking at each individual raw carrier field provided and seeing if there's a match on 2,000 patterns.